# Django Rest Framework JWT login required

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using django rest framework jwt authentication. I get token successfully and can add token to cookie. But when i try to reach views that requires login, JWT authentication is not working. Always redirects to login.html.

Http request header:

> Authorization:    JWT
> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjozLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NjU3NDgwLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFkbWluQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.Ro507cIEisRle_iKgH4dm3-tSbrrsaCUYtP2CIK9jLM
>
> Cookie:   token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjozLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NjU3NDgwLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFkbWluQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9.Ro507cIEisRle_iKgH4dm3-tSbrrsaCUYtP2CIK9jLM

```
class SystemUserView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, user_id):
        users = list(User.objects.all().values('email', 'id', 'username'))
        return HttpResponse(HttpResponse(json.dumps(users), content_type="application/json"))
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .views import SystemUserView, UserAuthenticationView
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^login/?$', UserAuthenticationView.login, name="index"),
    url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', SystemUserView.as_view(), name='user'),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
]
```

Django version :(1, 11, 5, 'final', 0)

Python 3.6.2

https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt

Comment: What is the version of django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 class SystemUserView(View):
```

Looks like you are importing a Django view, not a DRF [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/). DRF and Django use different authentication systems. If you are authenticated with JWT towards DRF, Django Views will still redirect you to the login page.

Here is an example of a DRF view using normal Token Authentication. I haven't tested it and you will have to adapt it for JWT, but it should lead you onto the right path.

```
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ListUsers(APIView):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    """
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, user_id):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
        users = list(User.objects.all().values('email', 'id', 'username'))
        return Response(users)
```

Also, please consider using a [DRF serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) for converting the user object to json.

Comment: Thanks it works now, what is the best way to redirect the user if user is not authenticated/login ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with your question, sorry. If user is not authenticated, DRF will return an HTTP 403 error and your APIView will not be called. That's the correct behavior for an API, so you don't really have to take care of this case.

Comment: so let me give you more information, i am trying to develop a website that use token authentication.(keeps token in cookie). So if user is not authenticated i want to redirect user to login page, if user hasn't permission to operate i must redirect the user to you_are_not_allowed_to_see.html. django view has login_required decarator, if user is not logged in, it redirects to LOGIN_URL. My motivation to use JWT is just login control. Am I missing something or doing wrong?

Comment: @RockOnGom It sounds like you are building a website (to be consumed with a browser) not an API. Is that possible? Because an API should usually not redirect the user to a log in page. `LOGIN_URL` is a django setting that is used for websites, not APIs.