# Django: ViewSets not accepting login required, rending SessionAuthentication useless

Tags: python, django, authentication, token

I am having issues using the DRF SessionAuthentication with views defined as ModelViewSets. The "LoginRequiredMixin" works fine in generics views, but I really don't like those as they require me to define all the urls manually and set them in the proper order. Very tedious when ViewSets allow you to define routes way more neatly.

I have tried using the "@login_required" decorator following Django's doc [authentication login()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login), but it doesn't accept it. Have tried specifying the authentication_class SessionAuthentication in my ViewSet but to no avail, following those posts:

- [JWT required login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265104/django-rest-framework-jwt-login-required)
- [login required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231682/how-to-use-login-required-in-django-rest-view)

Current FooBar_views.py file. The only way I have here so far to make sure a user is authenticated, is to check his JWT provided in the headers of his http request.

`foobar_vews.py with ViewSets`

```py
# @login_required not being accepted when imported
class FooBarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Foo Bar ViewSet calling various serializers depending on request type (GET, PUT etc.)
    """

    # Trying to filter FooBars list by status: Exluding unwanted ones
    queryset = FooBar.objects.exclude(status__name = 'SOLD').exclude(status__name = 'DELETED').order_by('id').reverse()

    # mapping serializer into the action
    serializer_classes = {
        'list': FooBarIndexSerializer,
        'retrieve': FooBarDetailsSerializer,
        'create': FooBarCreateSerializer,
    }

    # Your default serializer
    default_serializer_class = FooBarIndexSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """
        Method to detect request type (GET, PUT etc.) and select corresponding serializer.
        """
        return self.serializer_classes.get(self.action, self.default_serializer_class)

    # TODO: Move this to the permissions.py file?
    def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Method to apply permissions depending on request type (GET, PUT etc.)
        """
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return [permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly()]
        elif self.request.method == 'POST':
            return [permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsArtist()]
        else:  # PUT, PATCH, DELETE
            return [permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsOwner()]
```

Equivalent I'd need to define if using generics views. As can be seen, I don't need to add any "isAuthenticated" permission class as the "LoginRequiredMixin" checks that the user is logged, by checking the sessionId and CSRFToken.

Problem here, I need to manually define all the corresponding urls in the url.py file. Which is tedious and gets confusing as the FooBarListView  and FooBarCreateView should normally be the same url, but different requests surch as GET and POST.

`foobar_vews.py with generic views`

```py
class FooBarListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListAPIView):
   queryset = FooBar.objects.all()
   serializer_class = FooBarIndexSerializer

class FooBarDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
   queryset = FooBar.objects.all()
   serializer_class = FooBarDetailsSerializer

# TODO: Voir pour passer aux modelViews
class FooBarCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateAPIView):
   queryset = FooBar.objects.all()
   serializer_class = FooBarCreateSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsOwner]

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       user=self.request.user
       serializer.save(user=user)

class FooBarUpdateDestroyView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateDestroyAPIView):
   queryset=FooBar.objects.all()
   serializer_class = FooBarDetailsSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsOwner]
```

Therefore, is there a way to check a user is looged in ViewSets or am I forced to use a JWT authentication system, save the tokens client-side (is that even safe?), and from the front-end make sure that for every request the user provides those in the headers?

Any help on how to implement this in ViewSets would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First thing:** You have to understand that `Decorators` can only be used on functions, you can not use it in class based views the way you have used it. So its obvious that django viewsets will not accept the `@login_required` decorator.

So question is, can you decorate the methods of a class? the answer is, **YES**.
Here is the django docs [Decorating the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class), its says,

> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate
>   the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the
>   dispatch() method of the class.
>
> A method on a class isn’t quite the same as a standalone function, so
>   you can’t just apply a function decorator to the method – you need to
>   transform it into a method decorator first. The method_decorator
>   decorator transforms a function decorator into a method decorator so
>   that it can be used on an instance method. For example:

```
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So when using ViewSets and overriding the get_permission method, how could the decorator be used?
If permissions are defined on the request type, how can the login be required for some and not others based on this decorator ?
Does using generics views make more sense or is better practice is this case?

Comment: In fact in this certain case, using generic views make more sense. @MaxenceP

Comment: So in this case as you say, to use the SessionAuthentication from the DRF, if permissions vary from one type request to another, generics views are better suited. Even if it means defining all the URLs manually ?
Would using a simple JWT and storing it in a cookie or such on the client side make sense, would it be safe or not recommended since the session system is established ? @Md.TanvirRaihan

Comment: If you use JWT ,  you should have refresh token to generate access token as access token should be expired after some time. Thus the security issue will not be vulnerable even if you store the access token on a client side local storage. @MaxenceP

Comment: So I could keep using the JWT authentication system, store both the access and refresh token client side and make sure that it is provided in each request's provider. Would that basically replace the SessionAuthentication system entirely?

Comment: Yes, if you are using JWT authentication, then in general there is no need to use SessionAuthentication  at the same time.  you can check this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication to have some understanding of difference between Session Authentication vs Token Authentication

Comment: Its my pleasure!